# VCSEL to project a 2D array of dots

Tags: led, light, laser, laser-diode, open-source

#### Background

Apple iPhone Face ID uses [VCSEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical-cavity_surface-emitting_laser) inside its *dot projector* to project infrared dots into a person face. Then an infrared camera captures the pattern to be used in a [structured light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_light) algorithm to detect the 3D shape of face.

I'm interested in reproducing the above procedure by an open source project.

Someone has captured the projected dots by an infrared camera [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/stormlv/28931790887):

[image: Projected dots]

#### First question

Maybe the first hardware I need is an affordable VCSEL projector. I'm willing to purchase the VCSEL from a vendor if it is feasible. I wonder if there is any affordable VCSEL projector which is:

- High-quality enough, to be used by a structured light algorithm
- Affordable, ideally in the range of $100x or less
- It's OK to work with visible light. I mean, being infrared is *not* a priority

#### Other questions

I wonder whether such an open source project is even feasible? Would I be able to pull it off? Does anyone have any similar experience?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XBOX kinect which does exactly that, [and was hacked and used in projects by many people](https://www.google.com/search?q=kinect%20hacked).

[Open Kinect](https://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a good place to start.

[image]
[src](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F453245149992228841%2F&psig=AOvVaw3Qp9PxcZuON1IUm6SiuWcK&ust=1616754826849000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwiQnLWan8vvAhUNpJ4KHYrKACkQjhx6BAgAEBI)

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into it =)